# How can I make bluetooth and wifi available again?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, bluetooth

Ok, I have been experiencing some issues regarding my wifi and bluetooth connections ever since I upgraded Xubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10 which I did a few weeks ago.

Now, the thing is: I can't seem to be able to enable wifi because it is "hard blocked", something that had never happened before with previous versions of ubuntu/Xubuntu. I've had this laptop for quite some time.

At the same time I can't seem to be able to enable bluetooth, nor can I open the "bluetooth device manager" because I get this error:

[image]

But it won't get enabled.

The weird thing is that all previously paired devices get automatically connected when turned on but I can't pair new ones because I can't open the Device manager.

This is rfkill input:

```
rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      sony-wifi      unblocked   blocked
 1 bluetooth sony-bluetooth unblocked   blocked
 2 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0           unblocked unblocked
```

So, if bluetooth were actually hard blocked, how come the old devices can get connected? I believe the system is faulty, reading (for some reason) that the bluetooth is hard blocked but it is actually working (there's a connection, I can see the laptop being shown in other devices to be paired; it isn't actually "off")

Right now I have it connected to my phone:

[image]

I would like to know how to solve this problem. I have to idea how the system works but in my humble opinion, it is misreading something, interpreting that the bluetooth is OFF, as well as the wifi.

There have been a couple of days when I would turn on the laptop to find the wifi working normally... But then, after I turn off the laptop and turn it on again, the wifi was disabled again.

I have created a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1995297), but it hasn't been paid attention to, I guess because this doesn't affect as many people as to worry.

Comment: Try in terminal `echo "blacklist sony-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf` then reboot

Comment: It worked! :D Thank you so much!!

Comment: Oh, once someone had told me to use this command: `echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> sudo /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. I see now it was wrong.